# Keeping records in sync in denormalized data models

Tags: cassandra, nosql, denormalization

I am reading "Cassandra: The Definitive Guide", and I am trying to understand how denormalization works.

They have a data model with two tables containing hotel information, a "hotels" table, and a "hotels_by_poi" table (poi stands for points of interest). In each table, they include the name, phone, address of the hotel.

My understanding is they do this because the hotels_by_poi table is optimized for the query where you are searching for a hotel by a point of interest (clusters hotels by the hotel_id but partitions on poi_name), and the hotel table is for queries where you are querying for a specific hotel (partitioned on hotel_id).

However, I wonder how we ensure this data stays in sync for updates? Since we don't really have transactions it seems (there are light weight transactions (which I think works for maybe a row in a table?, and batches which don't actually seems to offer any transnational guarantees).

For example, if I want to update the hotel name, I need to execute these queries

```
UPDATE hotel.hotels
SET name = 'Updated Hotel Name'
WHERE hotel_id = 1234;

# For each poi_id associated with my hotel
UPDATE hotel.hotels_by_poi
SET name = 'Updated Hotel Name'
WHERE hotel_id = 1234 AND poi_id = 5678;
```

So if a hotel was near 5 points of interest, this would be 6 queries in total.

However, it could happen that two updates to the hotel name happen around the same time. Now we have a race condition between each set of queries. We could run into a situation where 3 of the first update win, and 3 of the second update win. Leaving an inconsistency.

How do we handle synchronizing this information correctly in databases like Cassandra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [BATCH statements](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlBatch.html) to achieve atomicity. Put the 6 queries in a single batch so all of them are either executed together.

Comment: atomicity in this situation means that if one insert/update succeeds all will succeed, but doesn't give any kind of transaction guarantee. From the link you posted, "Cassandra does no other transactional enforcement at the batch level. For example, there is no batch isolation unless the batch operation is writing to a single partition."

Comment: If you read "Batching conditional updates" I think you can use lightweight transactions to avoid the race.

Put the following DML statements in the batch

`UPDATE hotel.hotels_by_poi
  SET name = 'Updated Hotel Name'
  WHERE hotel_id = 1234 AND poi_id = 5678
  IF name = ‘Old Name’;`

Comment: Yes! That would do it! Thanks.

Comment: Thinking about it again it also depends on your replication factor and consistency level. Let's say you use RF 3 and write CL ONE. You might see successful writes but still have the race condition, depending on which nodes you hit in your clients, until the data is consistent. Eventually it should be right since the update with last timestamp will be consistent

Comment: Is it possible for them to have the same timestamp? Not sure how the syncing of nodes works. Does it take into account the light weight transactions? If it does, then one of the batches might be thrown away entirely, which would be fine too.

Probably better to just write with higher consistency level if I need it to be correct.

Comment: If you use a client side timestamp then you can ensure both writes have the same timestamp,

Comment: Syncing of nodes does not take lightweight transactions into account.